# Setting collation and charset per model/table in Django and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, django

In Django it is really easy to set the collation and charset for a connection to MySQL. Here is an example of how to do that using the `mysql-connector-python` Django engine:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'secret-password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'use_pure': True,
            'sql_mode': 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
            'charset': 'utf8mb4',
            'collation': 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        },
        'TEST': {
            'CHARSET': 'utf8mb4',
            'COLLATION': 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        }
    }
}
```

However, this sets the charset and collation for the whole database (all of the tables). I'd like to be able to specify this on only the tables or even fields/columns that I know need this collation/charset (for emoji for example).

The problem I'm having is that I'm depending on some models/tables from other Django apps that specify `CharField` with max lengths larger than the new collation/charset can handle for indexing a unique field. Specifically, there is an app that defines `CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)` which causes, `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes` error.

**Is there a way to specify the charset and collation on a column/field or table/model level?**

UPDATE: I've already tried the solution [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18392#comment:45) but this code does not apply to unique indexes which don't seem to be able to have a limit set on the index.